# When do I use a callback function in JavaScript programming

Tags: node.js, callback

I have a very simple app, that mainly collects data from the native ‘os’ nodejs module and then write to the DOM.  I don’t really care which function updates the page first or last, and where my functions do not rely on one another, do I need to use callback functions?

The underlying noob question I have is, “when exactly do I need to use callback, vs when I don’t?”

Is there a millisecond time benchmark, where if a function is going to take longer than n seconds, then use a callback?

Comment: Whenever the operation to be performed needs to do something asynchronous, and you aren't using a `Promise`. A heavy function may well run synchronously, but take multiple ms (or even seconds, rarely) to finish.

Comment: It's not about milliseconds. It's primarily about synchronous vs asynchronous execution. *I have a very simple app ... do I need to use callback functions?* - obviously, this depends on your app, which wasn't shown. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to keep the question on-topic. If the code works as intended, this may be off-topic for SO, consider asking it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You use a callback if some of your code *absolutely needs* to have the result of another command. For example, a command that modifies some element on the page must have the result of another command that finds that element. So you call the function that looks for the element (e.g. document.findElementById) and as an argument to that call, you provide a callback function containing the commands that make use of the result.

Comment: CertainPerformance, I’m not using a Promise yet, until I can nail callbacks.  Thanks for your responses CertainPerformance, Estus and Jim.  I have learnt a bit more from a combination of the three. I think a following question I have then is “how do I know which code is going to continue on before previous code has finished?”  Eg. How would I know that findElementById needs a callback in the first place.  Is it by trial and error, where if I don’t use a callback, and get a bunch of “undefined”, I know I need to use callbacks?

Comment: To use promises you don't need deep prior knowledge of callbacks.

Comment: @ajhstn Functions that have to read/write from/to somewhere – standard input/output, files, databases, connections, or in this case a webpage – or that call another function, should be used with a callback (or a promise). Only things that are part of the direct internal flow of the code can be assumed to deliver before the next statement gets executed.

Comment: @JimDanner thank you, that’s exactly the knowledge and answer I’m looking for.